# Is there a way to using date format's offset parameter with colon?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm using java's SimpleDateFormat, here is my code:

    `Date date = new Date(); 
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(strDate);`

Which print out:

> 2019-11-15T11:59:47.289+0200

But, I want to have a colon inside the offset, which means it need to look like this:

> 2019-11-15T11:59:47.289+02:00

Is there a way to adding a time zone that printed out like the second example here?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is not a time zone (like UTC), it is an offset (like +01:00).

You can use the modern date time API `java.time`, which has a built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, that formats the offset as desired:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public class StackoverflowDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

The output on my system is this:

```
2019-11-15T11:30:46.532+01:00
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed my question. Also, accept this answer as, in my opinion, it much more simple and readable then using XXX as suggested below.

Comment: @Moshe9362 Thanks for accepting, I'm glad it helped. Consider using `java.time` for all operations on dates, times, calendary, time zones, offsets and so on. Don't write new programs using `java.util.Date`, that's legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

this snippet below gives result like this

> 2019-11-15T16:03:53+05:30

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(new Date()));
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: You have forgotten the millisecond part.

Comment: @MenoHochschild ohh! thanx

Answer (score 1):

Your format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

Comment: Wrong pattern! Look at your hour-part.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned that the formatted string should contain the 24-hr based hour format. So I used the pattern in OP's original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use `DateTimeFormatter`.

You can find documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Hey Konrad, thank you for answering, a code sample would be nice to complete your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for wanting to contribute. Your answer isn’t really much more than a link. Such isn’t really helpful according to experience. Please include some essence from the linked page in your answer. You can always edit your answer if you want to improve it. I agree that it’s best to use `DateTimeFormatter`.